# Как сделать, чтобы код выводил названия в столбик, а не просто списком?

Tags: python, python-3.x, перенос

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests


def page_proc(page: Soup) -> list:
    news_headers = []
    for header in page.find_all('h4', {'class': 'media-heading'}):
        news_headers.append(header.text.strip())
    return news_headers


def sandbox(base_url: str) -> list:
    headers = []
    with requests.Session() as session:
        first_page = Soup(session.get(base_url).content, 'html.parser')
        pages_qty = int(first_page.find('li', {'class': 'pager-last'}).a['href'].rpartition('=')[-1])

        headers.extend(page_proc(first_page))

        pg = Soup(session.get(base_url).content, 'html.parser')
        headers.extend(page_proc(pg))

        return headers


if __name__ == '__main__':
print(sandbox('http://hkotso.ru/novosti'))
```

Как сделать, чтобы код выводил названия в столбик, а не просто списком?

Вот что он выводит:

> ['Гигиена при гриппе, коронавирусной инфекции и других ОРВИ', 'Стань
>   волонтёром Конституции!', 'Внимание, вакансия', '«В служении верном
>   Отчизне клянусь»', 'Информационная встреча с представителями воинской
>   части № 23227', 'Информационная встреча с представителями воинской
>   части', 'Деловая игра "Собеседование с работодателем"', 'Предложение
>   работы в воинской части', 'Итоги краевого конкурса профессионального
>   мастерства', 'Информационная встреча и презентация «Поискового
>   движения России»', 'Классный час "Великие женщины"', 'Спортивный
>   праздник, приуроченный ко всемирному женскому дню', 'Бинарный урок на
>   тему: "Классификация, ассортимент, пищевая ценность, рецептуры
>   приготовления супов сложного приготовления"', 'Ознакомительная
>   экскурсия по корпоративно-отраслевому музею АО «Газпром
>   газораспределение  Дальний Восток»', 'Открытие фотовыставки
>   «Заповедники Болонского международного водно-болотного угодья»',
>   'Гигиена при гриппе, коронавирусной инфекции и других ОРВИ', 'Стань
>   волонтёром Конституции!', 'Внимание, вакансия', '«В служении верном
>   Отчизне клянусь»', 'Информационная встреча с представителями воинской
>   части № 23227', 'Информационная встреча с представителями воинской
>   части', 'Деловая игра "Собеседование с работодателем"', 'Предложение
>   работы в воинской части', 'Итоги краевого конкурса профессионального
>   мастерства', 'Информационная встреча и презентация «Поискового
>   движения России»', 'Классный час "Великие женщины"', 'Спортивный
>   праздник, приуроченный ко всемирному женскому дню', 'Бинарный урок на
>   тему: "Классификация, ассортимент, пищевая ценность, рецептуры
>   приготовления супов сложного приготовления"', 'Ознакомительная
>   экскурсия по корпоративно-отраслевому музею АО «Газпром
>   газораспределение  Дальний Восток»', 'Открытие фотовыставки
>   «Заповедники Болонского международного водно-болотного угодья»']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
for x in sandbox('http://hkotso.ru/novosti'):
    print(x)
```

---

Еще можно так:

```
print(*sandbox('http://hkotso.ru/novosti'), sep='\n')
```

Тут есть несколько небольших хитростей:

- Семантика функции [print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)
- `*<список>` -- оператор `*` в этом контексте раскладывает элементы списка по безымянным параметрам функции, эти параметры у функции называются `*objects`
- По умолчанию, несколько параметров `print` (`*objects`) разделяются пробелом (см. выше на `sep=' '`), но мы указываем значение `'\n'`, что разделяет элементы новой строкой

Answer (score 0):

Объёмные списки и словари (в том числе с несколькими уровнями вложенности) удобно смотреть с помощью модуля `pprint`.

Просто импортируйте его и используйте вместо стандартного print:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(big_list_or_dict)
```